# memory efficient method to get counts by unique object attribute in keyed dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary of objects like so:

```
{
  'January 2014': [
    <-- OBJECT_NAME: "Steve's Object"
        CREATED: Datetime(1,1,2014)
        CREATOR: Steve -->,
    <-- OBJECT_NAME: "Another Object"
        CREATED: Datetime(1,1,2014)
        CREATOR: Jeff -->
  ],
  'February 2014': [
    <-- OBJECT_NAME: "Steve's New Object"
        CREATED: Datetime(2,1,2014)
        CREATOR: Steve -->,
    <-- OBJECT_NAME: "foo"
        CREATED: Datetime(2,1,2014)
        CREATOR: bar -->
  ]
  ...
}
```

now, what I want to do is iterate through all the keys and lists of this collection, and return a count of UNIQUE creators. The purpose being, I want to see all "new" creators that joined each month. Currently, I am doing it in this way but it is fairly inefficient:

```
seen_creators = []
uniq_count = collections.Counter()
for key, value in objects_by_month.iteritems():
  for obj in value:
    if obj.CREATOR not in seen_creators:
      seen_creators.append(obj.CREATOR)
      uniq_count[key] += 1
return uniq_count
```

result: `Counter('January 2014': 2, 'February 2014': 1)`

I can't help but think there's a more efficient way to do it that doesn't involve createding a list which will, for all intents and purposes, be thrown away after the fact. Is there?

Comment: Without changing the algorithm, instead of a `list` you could use a `set` to provide much faster lookup.

Comment: Since you are iterating over a dictionary, you have no gaurantee that `'February 2014'` will come after `'January 2014'`.  So your current approach is incorrect.

Comment: Why are you concerned about memory usage here?  Do you have millions of different CREATORS?  I ask this because I think there may be no bottleneck here.  I see a *possible* performance bottleneck in that `seen_creators` would be better as a `set` due to the lookup times to test if an item is a member of a list.

Comment: There could be up to twenty thousand entries in the dictionary.

Comment: Twenty thousand unique strings in a data structure is unlikely eat up much memory.  Especially as the list only stores a reference to the strings.

Comment: You could make seen_creators a dictionary and add the new creators to it.  If it's unordered, it should be quicker finding keys in it than elements in a list.